How to do na.rm with conventional binary operators
I have a data set where missing values are represented by either NA or 9. (Yes, I should recode the 9s to NA, but I didn't make the dataset.) I want to count the sum of the number of NAs and the number of 9s and remove those cases where the sum of the numbers of NAs and 9s is at least 5.
The data frame looks like this:
  final_id year nl_eco_sch_1 nl_eco_sch_6 nl_eco_sch_3 nl_eco_sch_5 nl_eco_sch_4
1    10002 2023            5            5            5            5            5
2    10016 2023            4            4            4            4            4
3    10019 2023            5            4            3            2            2
4    10024 2023            5            5            5            5            5
5    10029 2023            5            5            5            5            5
6    10049 2023           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA

In addition, I have a character vector with the names of the columns of interest:
schl.context <- c("nl_eco_sch_1", "nl_eco_sch_6", "nl_eco_sch_3", "nl_eco_sch_5", "nl_eco_sch_4")

I found most of what I was looking for is this fine post 1:
Here is the code I use to process this:
peeps.23 <- longitudinal %>%
    select(final_id, year, all_of(schl.context)) %>%
    filter(year == 2023) %>%
    mutate(na.num=rowSums(is.na(select(., one_of(schl.context)))),
           nine.num=rowSums(select(., one_of(schl.context)) == 9)) ### %>%
   ## filter(sum(na.num, nine.num, na.rm=TRUE) >= 5)

the result is this:
  final_id year nl_eco_sch_1 nl_eco_sch_6 nl_eco_sch_3 nl_eco_sch_5 nl_eco_sch_4 na.num nine.num
1    10002 2023            5            5            5            5            5      0        0
2    10016 2023            4            4            4            4            4      0        0
3    10019 2023            5            4            3            2            2      0        0
4    10024 2023            5            5            5            5            5      0        0
5    10029 2023            5            5            5            5            5      0        0
6    10049 2023           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA      5       NA

You can see that it counts the numbers of NAs as hoped, but because we are testing if schl.context==9 I get the number of 9s as NA if there are any NAs in the row. I tried putting na.rm=TRUE in various places but nowhere does it work.
I also want to filter out observations that are all missing -- i.e., the sum of the number of NAs and the number of 9s is at least 5 (it should never be greater than 5 but). The last line in the code above (commented out for now) does not work, either:
filter(sum(na.num, nine.num, na.rm=TRUE) >= 5)

I originally had it as filter(na.num + nine.num >= 5) but that produces the same problem. I tried the operator function equivalent:     filter(`+`(na.num, nine.num, na.rm=TRUE)), which didn't work either.
In short, what do I do with something like variable==9 or var1 + var2>=5 when there are missing values that you want to ignore?
Any suggestions?

It's easier if you interpret NA as "unknown" rather than just "missing". If a value is NA, you (or R) can't know whether if its ==9 or not, and so the result of the comparison is also unknown (i.e., NA). This results in having NA elements in the rowSums() argument, and an NA as a result.

Given your column names variable schl.context you can simply subset your longitudinal data.frame to have all data points of interest and create a matrix of TRUE/FALSE values that test if the value is NA OR equal to 9 to get rowSums count of these T/F values:
schl.context <- c("nl_eco_sch_1", "nl_eco_sch_6", "nl_eco_sch_3", "nl_eco_sch_5", "nl_eco_sch_4")
logitudinal$nine_or_NA_above5 <- rowSums(is.na(longitudinal[schl.context]) | longitudinal[schl.context]==9) >= 5

You can then filter the data.frame by nine_or_NA_above5==TRUE as this has identified the count where NA or ==9 values are greater or equal to 5.  If you're only looking at year 2023, then this can be done on that subset as you've already done.  Otherwise you can group by year to get the nine_or_NA count by year and then filter. However, this objective isn't quite clear from the question or sample data.

It seems that previous answer (@Soren's) left out the first part of the problem.
Since there's no "9" on your sample, here's some toy data with "9", more "NA" and a column not of your interest (nl_eco_sch_xx) :
# library(tidyverse)

# -------------------
longitudinal <- tibble::tribble(
  ~final_id, ~year, ~nl_eco_sch_1, ~nl_eco_sch_xx, ~nl_eco_sch_6, ~nl_eco_sch_3, ~nl_eco_sch_5, ~nl_eco_sch_4,
  10002,  2023,             5,             NA,             5,             5,             5,             5,
  10016,  2023,             4,              9,             4,             4,             4,             4,
  10019,  2023,             5,             99,             4,             3,             2,             2,
  99999,  2023,             9,              1,             9,             9,             9,             9,
  10024,  2023,             9,              2,            NA,            NA,             5,             5,
  10029,  2023,             9,              3,             9,             5,             5,             5,
  10049,  2023,            NA,              7,            NA,            NA,            NA,            NA)

# Your columns of interest:
schl.context <- c("nl_eco_sch_1", "nl_eco_sch_6", "nl_eco_sch_3", "nl_eco_sch_5", "nl_eco_sch_4")

# Your values of interest:
my_values <- c(9, NA)

The code:
#1 Counting `my_values` 
peeps.23 <- longitudinal %>% 
  select(final_id, year, any_of(schl.context)) %>%
  pivot_longer(any_of(schl.context), values_to = "value") %>% 
  filter(value %in% my_values) %>% 
  summarise(.by = c(final_id, value), n = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, names_prefix = "num_")

#2 Joining the original data and the counting
peeps.23 <- left_join(
    select(longitudinal, final_id, year, any_of(schl.context)), 
    peeps.23, by = c("final_id"))

#3 Removing undesired rows (all missing):
peeps.23 <- filter(peeps.23, !if_all(any_of(schl.context), \(x) x %in% my_values))

The output:
> peeps.23
# A tibble: 5 × 9
  final_id  year nl_eco_sch_1 nl_eco_sch_6 nl_eco_sch_3 nl_eco_sch_5 nl_eco_sch_4 num_9 num_NA
     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <int>  <int>
1    10002  2023            5            5            5            5            5    NA     NA
2    10016  2023            4            4            4            4            4    NA     NA
3    10019  2023            5            4            3            2            2    NA     NA
4    10024  2023            9           NA           NA            5            5     1      2
5    10029  2023            9            9            5            5            5     2     NA

PS. final_id must be unique.
Hope it helps.
